# alert if empty input and do ajax if not empty

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

How to show alert if empty input?

and do ajax if not empty!

thanks.. now is working!

thanks everybody..

thanks to stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. At the moment, your question isn't clear on what you want to get done. Could you edit your question to clarify please? To learn more on asking good questions, see [ask]. Thank you!

Comment: *offtopic* From a User Interface perspective, there's **no sense at all** to allow a user to click something - if the condition does not fit your expectations. What I mean is: make a submit button `disabled`, than after the form is properly filled, just make your submit *good to go*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using

```
$("#pic-upload").val().length == 0
```

It will also count for **new line character**, and the length will be **greater than 0**
So instead of that you should use

```
$("#pic-upload").val()== ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify This part

```
$('#submit').click(function(){ // if click
    if ($.trim($("#pic-upload").val()== ''){ // if empty input
        alert('empty'); 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: tahnks! this is working.. thanks everybody.. thanks stackoverflow!